# Laravel relation displaying null on eager load

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

A Laravel relation is displaying null on eager load. However, it works when the relation is accessed normally.

```php
class Student extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // or null
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function document()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Document');
    }

    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Contact');
    }
}
```

The contract relation returns null when I use the following.

```php
Student::with('contact')->get()
```

However it works when I do the following. What could be the cause of this?

```php
$student = Student::findOrFail($id);
$contact = $student->contact;
```

Comment: See examples here for [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Maybe this code help for you: `$students = Student::with(array('contact' => function($query) {
    $query->select('id','phone');
}))->get();`

Answer (score 0):

`Student::with('contact')->get();` returns a `Collection` of `Student` instances, which you can loop and access the `contact` relationship:

```
$students = Student::with('contact')->get();
foreach($students AS $student){
  dd($student->contact); 
  // Can be `null` or an instance of `Contact`
}
```

When you call `Student::findOrFail($id);`, you're getting a single instance of `Student`, which you can directly access `contact`:

```
$student = Student::with('contact')->findOrFail($id);
dd($student->contact);
// Again, can be `null` or an instance of `Contact`
```

The `with()` clause is eager loading, and doesn't do anything until you try to access `$student->contact`, but due to the nature of `hasOne()`, it can be `null`.

Comment: ```
 public function ajaxData(Request $request){
        return DataTables::of(Student::with('contact')->get())->toJson();
    }
```

Comment: How do I use this statement then ?

Comment: That will create a `DataTable` of `Student` records, cast to `JSON` with a `student.contact` property available that is either `null` or a `JSON` version of a contact. I'm not familiar with `DataTable` usage as you have defined there, but either way, it's an array of records, not a single record (which is the result of `findOrFail()`)

Comment: I think you are wrong about this , eager loading uses a join statement so it cannot be null even if $student->contact is not called

Comment: I'm saying this because I have used the same code in another project and it works , I don't know why this is causing error in this project

Comment: Right, but `hasOne()` and `belongsTo()` can both return `null`; it depends on if your database columns are `nullable()`. *The Eager Load has nothing to do with that; `join` statements can still return 0 records, which is treated as `null` when translated to PHP* (That's irrelevant actually)

Comment: @FaseihSaad Laravel relationships (eager loaded or not) do not use sql join statements. They are completely separate queries, and the hydrated models are matched after the queries are run.